# c++ hadoop streaming can't support load dict?

Tags: c++11, hadoop-streaming

Here is the code as below:

```
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int  result = load("./model.bin");
    string line;
    while(getline(cin,line))
    {
        auto fields = split(line,' ');
        auto label_fields = split(fields[0],':');
        float ctr = 0.0;
        for(int i = 1;i<fields.size();i++)
        {
             auto feature = strtoll(fields[i].c_str(), NULL, 10);
             auto iter = data_.find(feature);
             if(iter!=data_.end())
             {
                 ctr += iter->second;
             }
        }
        ctr = 1.0f / (1.0f + exp(-ctr)) ;
        cout << label_fields[0] << "\t" << ctr << "\t" << data_.size() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why is `data_size` 0 when run hadoop streaming?

In local disk, the model bin is loaded correctly.

Comment: the file should be in HDFS

Comment: can't it be uploaded automation?

Comment: do you run your app by "$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop  jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar" command? You may pass all necessary files to that command by "-file <filename>" option one by one, or pass all files at once by "-files <file_1>, <file_2>, ..., <file_n>" option

Comment: /data/clusterserver/hadoop/bin/hadoop jar /data/clusterserver/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.6.4.jar \
  -files "$BIN_PATH/predict" \
  -files "./model.bin" \
  -D mapred.job.name="predict_hadoop" \
  -D mapred.reduce.tasks=0 \
  -D mapreduce.job.maps=10 \
  -input "/user/test" \
  -output "$output_path" \
  -mapper "predict "

Comment: here is my shell codes,of course,it is added

Comment: how about removing "./" this prefix from "load" argument in your c++ code? I guess, the mapper and reducer will append the proper hadoop path to the file name automatically, so you don't need to specify any folders. try using "load("model.bin")"

Comment: it still doesn't work